# knex join limit query

Tags: node.js, join, knex.js

I'm using node.js and knexjs

I need to make an SQL request like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0) AS t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.t_id = t1.id
```

Is it possible to make it with knex query builder?

Comment: I've formatted your code to make it more readable (and more obvious as code). Take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to help improve your questions in the future.

Answer (score 5):

```
knex({ 
  t1: knex('t').limit(50).offset(0) 
}).join('t2', 't2.t_id', 't1.id')
```

https://runkit.com/embed/gteg0h052e37